# iOS navigationController pushViewController not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uinavigationcontroller, storyboard

I have a storyboard with a `UINavigationController`. The root view controller of the navigation controllers is called rootViewController.

I am trying to programmatically change the view controller (depending on other conditions) to another view controller called `loginViewController`.

I am trying to do this in the `viewDidLoad` from the rootViewController like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    [super viewDidLoad];

    loginViewController *viewController = [[loginViewController alloc] init];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];

}
```

I am not getting any errors but it's not working.

It just loads the navigation controller with the top nav back button but the rest of the screen is black. It's like it's not loading any view controller.

I am trying to figure out what I am doing wrong.

Any help with this would be great.

Thanks

Comment: Did you add your viewController with UINavigationController in AppDelegate? like that UINavigationController *navigation = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.viewController];

Comment: How is the loginViewControllers view initialized? With a xib? In code? From a storyboard? Sounds to me like you're pushing a ViewController without a view.

Comment: why are you pushing the viewcontroller in viewdidload?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First add loginViewController class in storyboard and and connect ViewController class to loginViewController class and give identifier name as "identifier_Name".

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"identifier_Name" sender:nil];
}

-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"identifier_Name"])
    {
        loginViewController *viewController = [segue destinationViewController];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using storyboard, create your login view in the storyboard, link your rootVC to the loginVC with a segue, choose an identifier (for example: "goToLogin"). and then to go in the login view, and use:

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"goToLogin" sender:self];
```